# SSIS Error code 0x80040E05

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis, etl, windows-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Error Message:

"Information: 0x4004300A at Testing1, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.

Warning: 0x80047076 at Testing1, SSIS.Pipeline: The output column "[Measures].[Distinct Count]" (18) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (13) and component "PIPELINE CUBE" (2) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance.

Information: 0x40043006 at Testing1, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.

Information: 0x40043007 at Testing1, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.

Error: 0xC0202009 at Testing1, PIPELINE CUBE [2]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred.

Error code: 0x80040E05.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server 2014 Analysis Services."  Hresult: 0x00000001  Description: "Error Code = 0x80040E05, External Code = 0x00000000:.".
Error: 0xC004701A at Testing1, SSIS.Pipeline: PIPELINE CUBE failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202009.

Information: 0x4004300B at Testing1, SSIS.Pipeline: "DB TEMP" wrote 0 rows.

Information: 0x40043009 at Testing1, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Task failed: Testing1"

My environment:

- SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013
- SQL Server 2014
- Windows Server 2012

Any clue why i am getting this error? - knowing that it used to be working successfully!

Comment: Excellent, the additional error and warning data improves the question. Not having much experience with connection SSIS to a cube, what specifically are you doing in this package? Have you redeployed the cube and could this package attempt to target an invalid cube id (I have some vague recollection of this being a thing with MDM cubes)

Comment: Simply, i am copying data from CUBE to database - this package is working perfect on my laptop, but i get this error when i run it on windows server - don't know if something is missing.

Comment: Try running the query that produces the OLE DB error in SSMS and see if you get a more specific error message.

Comment: I added the same query to ADO NET Source instead of OLE DB and it worked - any idea what might be wrong with the OLE DB source causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution for this issue is to use "**ADO.NET**" as source - the only disadvantage is you are going to add Data Conversion to convert from DT_STR to DT_WSTR then to any other types you need such as int.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Cube connection manager. Press F4. this will open the properties window. In the connection String, add **Format=tabular;** in the end
Eg: Data Source=(Server address>;Initial Catalog=;Provider=MSOLAP.5;Integrated Security=SSPI;Format=tabular;

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Microsoft OLE DB provider for Analysis Service 14.0 as it has this issue fixed.

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code - Do you have a link for that update? I'd love to get it installed, but am not sure which update. Have also looked for 14.0, but could only find 15.x.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was particularly resolved with the up-gradation to version 14.0 of 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Analysis Service'; 15.x, however, saw this problem returning back and could be a challenge to crush as it's still one of the listed bugs with SSIS.